# Can anyone confirm if the Samsung RC520 touchpad is correctly recognised in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, samsung

In 11.04 the touchpad is recognised as a PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse - checking around the various touchpad debug pages suggests that the kernal in 11.04 does not register it as a touchpad.

Can anyone confirm that this issue is resolved in 11.10?

Comment: Do you have any real problem or are you just researching?

Comment: I have a real problem in that I currently can't configure my touchpad and I would prefer not to go through the hassle of upgrading if it won't fix the problem (I'm otherwise happy with 11.04 and have a fair amount of 'unmanaged' software installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer but I had similar issue with 11.10. The fix developed by Seth Forshee available at https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/550625/comments/492 solved my problem and also worked for A LOT of people.

It is worth checking it out and asking there about it. It definetely might be the solution IF the output of `xinput list` on the shell shows you have an *Alps TouchPad*.